# caching automatically for new patches

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular, caching

- I have a huge angular 2 appliucation.
- for every two weeks we are giving a patch release.
- but everytime users need to clear the browser cache to see the js changes.
- is there any inbuild method in angular 2 or js or jquery where users can delete the cache automatically when they hit the url in the browser after our release.
- I thought of including that method in the below app.module.ts file since it includes all the modules
- can you tell me how to solve the problem.

```or-tag-here
import './rxjs-extensions';

import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';

import {Base} from './components/base/base';
import {playerUser} from './components/player/user';
import {player} from './components/player/player';

import {
    Routes,
    RouterModule,
    Router,
    ActivatedRoute,

    CanActivateChild,
    CanDeactivate,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot
} from "@angular/router";
import { titleService } from './components/title/titleService';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    MultiselectDropdownModule,
    AccordionModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Base,
    player,
    playerUser,
    playerFunctionalRoles,
  ],
  providers: [
  sportsUService,saveService,titleService],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to bundle your application?

If you are using angular cli, then cache busting mechanisms are in place (notice that the generated files have a hash associated with them). In which case you can disable caching within Nginx/Apache or whatever you are using to serve your site on `index.html` only.

This will download the new source files identified by the new hash code reference within the index.html.

In case you are using webpack only, make sure that cache busting is enabled .

This tutorial : https://powerspace.tech/how-to-cache-busting-with-webpack-5131b4af8826 shows you how to enable hashing and cache busting.

Comment: @JeaPaul thanks for your reply...I am trying to learn angular...if you explain me about this line that would be great so that in future I can do it by myself--->  In which case you can disable caching within Nginx/Apache or whatever you are using to serve your site on index.html only

Comment: hey we are using nodejs buildpack...any idea how to solve using this https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/node/